# Galois theory group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

Let $p$ and $q$ be any two distinct integers. Write down the Galois group of $Q( √p, √q)$ over $Q$ and identify it with some known group. Determine all the sub-fields of $Q( √p, √q)$.

$Attempt$:
I solve it  If $p$ and $q$ are primes then it is isomorphic to $Z$/$2Z$ $*$ $Z$/$2Z$ but what about arbitrary distinct integers I don't get idea.
I got that I need to consider also that what if product of $p*q$ is square or square-free.

Comment: Notice $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{q},\sqrt{p}):\mathbb{Q}] \leq 4$. So there are not so many groups to consider (basically, with some argument, only four).

Comment: Ok now I got it If  pq is square then it is isomorphic to Z/2Z if it is not then either Z/4Z OR Z/2Z * Z/2Z

Comment: Please tell me whether I am right or wrong

Comment: Well, there are some more cases to consider (for example, when the numbers are square themselves). Also you should be able to rule out the cyclic group with some basic facts about the field automorphisms in the galois group.

Comment: Can you please write some elaborate answer if possible?

Comment: if both number are square then it Automatically it becomes trivial Galois group is it Right if one is not then it isomorphic to Z/2Z or something else?suppose we consider sqrt 6 how could I find Galois group associated with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, let's start with determining the degree of the field extension to get an idea what the possible groups are. Since $$ \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p},\sqrt{q}) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p})(\sqrt{q}),$$ we can deduce that $$
[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p},\sqrt{q}) : \mathbb{Q}]=[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p},\sqrt{q}) : \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p})][\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p}) : \mathbb{Q}].$$
Both integers are zeros of the polynomial $X^2-p$ or $X^2-q$, therefore each extension can have degree of at most $2$. So the possible groups are $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ for degree $4$, $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ for degree $2$ and the trivial group for degree $1$. ($3$ is not possible since it is not a multiple of $2$).

Degree $1$ can only happen if both numbers are square (why?). So let's say $p$ is not a sqare, so $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p})$ is a proper field extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ with degree $2$. (Note the degree of the minimal polynomial). If $\sqrt{q}$ is contained in either $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p})$ we are done. If not we get another field extension of degree $2$, so overall we will have a degree of $4$. Now, if this extension would have the galois group $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$, we would need an element of degree $4$ in there. But note that the automorphisms only permute zeros of the same minimal polynomial, so $\sqrt{p}$ can only be mapped to itself or $-\sqrt{p}$ the same for $\sqrt{q}$. So you can write down all the automorphisms explicitlyand see, that there is no element of order $4$ and we have the group $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

You can get the subfields by looking at the different subgroups of the galois group. This shouldn't be too hard.